# Detect windows phone call click

Tags: html

I have tried giving dialUp     dial Up

This works fine in android phones but doesnot work in Windows.

Any work around for this. I tried onclick. 
Even That doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

There is no embedded "Call Button" in Windows Phones. If you mean to trigger Phone Call task, which will call a number/person, here's how:

```
PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();

phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = "123456789";
phoneCallTask.DisplayName = "TestNumber";

phoneCallTask.Show();
```